# Why is Model.associations an Array, but still supports sql queries?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

How is it possible that if you have two models (Model & Association) with a "has_many" relation, if you take the result : Model.associations, the object belongs to the Array Class (if you check Model.associations.class), but you still can append some query specifications on it, like Model.associations.where(...)?